# Multiple columns as one in an Google Sheets chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a Google Sheet tracking data over days, logging data at different times during the day, example:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way that I can have this data represented in a chart as one continuous line tracking throughout time?

This is an example of what I'm after, having put all of the data in one column.
[image]

Comment: Have you thought of trying the stacked line chart?

Comment: Isn't the current chart essentially a stacked line chart?
I am essentially wanting one continuous line/data set

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have is a line chart.

For stacked line charts use:

[image]

Comment: I see what you mean, but the chart doesn't come out in a style I am wanting. Please see my updated question for a bit more on what I'm after...

Comment: Set all lines except the top most ones to "No Outline", Set the topmost one to the colour and width you want.

Comment: An alternative is to just create a new columns summing all the values and use that for the chart

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible without changing your data structure:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,B2:E),",")))
```

Chart over resulting data

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a new column that has the data you want, and then chart that?

For example, add a column with the sum of the data on the right, and then chart that column.
That seems more straightforward to me and easier to understand.